# Is it possible to get a EntityEntry<T> from a IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a method that does **not** have the DbContext object (it is called by a method that does). While I can pass the DbContext as a parameter, I'm trying to avoid that as it's called  in 23 different places. Plus I prefer to minimize the number of parameters passed.

I do have an object that is an `IQueryable<T>` and an object of type `T`. Is there a way from those objects to get an `EntityEntry<T>`? Or an `IUpdateEntry<T>`?

It seems to me that the `IQueryable` should have a pointer to the `DbContext` somewhere/somehow. But I have not been able to find it.

Comment: _"It seems to me that the IQueryable should have a pointer to the DbContext"_ - no it should not. `IQueryable` is pretty general interface which abstracts over dynamic query analysis for query providers (so you can generate SQL from user defined code). It can be used by multiple query providers not only EF, and some of them do not have a `DbContext` concept (and potentially have nothing to do with database engines at all).

Comment: If you need to work with changetracker you need to pass one of the abstractions allowing it. Like `DbContext`, `DbSet`, `ChangeTracker` or something else.

Comment: @GuruStron Your comments make a lot of sense. If you write that up as an answer, happy to accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me that the `IQueryable` should have a pointer to the `DbContext`

No it should not. `IQueryable` is pretty general interface which abstracts over dynamic query analysis for query providers (so you can generate SQL from user defined code). It can be used by different query providers not only EF, and some of them do not have a `DbContext` concept (and have nothing to do with database engines at all, for example you can implement your custom query provider over filesystem - [see this blog](https://jacopretorius.net/2010/01/implementing-a-custom-linq-provider.html)).

In theory something would be possible via [`IQueryable.Provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable.provider?view=net-8.0) but even if it was possible it would be to much work and diving into EF Core internals.

If you need to work with change tracker you need to pass one of the abstractions allowing it. Like `DbContext`, `DbSet` or `ChangeTracker` (maybe there are some others which I have not thought of).